# Cannot install MysqlWorkbench on Windows 11 family edition 64bit

Tags: mysql-workbench, windows-11

The system is Windows 11 family edition 64bit

I installed the Microsoft Visual C++ 2019 library ( VC_redist.x64.exe ), I tried to install the Dotnet framework 4.5 but Windows aborts it because it says that there is already Dotnet installed. Now when I install MysqlWorkbench with the complete install option selected then the installation is not possible, I always get internal error 2503 and 2502. So how to fix it ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution, at the page 5 of the multiple responses of this forum there is a "simple" solution from MarkSun :

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/internal-error-25032502/28b361b7-b2d7-494d-8470-5969f6850f5a